# shift operation in gmp library

Tags: c++

I have to perform left shift and right shift and i am using gmp library.

I used code

```
#include<gmp.h>

mpz_t t;
mpz_init2(t,125);
mpz_set_ui(t,31);
mpz_mul_2exp(t , t , 35);
```

It give me value of t is zero. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: How are you observing the value? If I add `gmp_printf("%Zd\n", t);` to your code, it prints the expected value of `1065151889408`, not zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Try using mpz_init instead of mpz_init2.</strike>

Actually, it should work OK with your method, since the operation doesn't exceed the 125 bits that you assigned for t. I just tested it now. How are you inspecting the result? Have you used `gmp_printf ("%Zd\n", t);`?

To convert the string representation of a GMP integer to `std::string`, you can do something like this:

```
//get a pointer to GMP's internal memory deallocator function
void (*deallocator)(void *, size_t);
mp_get_memory_functions(NULL, NULL, &deallocator);

//get the string representation of input in binary
char *data = mpz_get_str(NULL, 2, input.data);

std::string output(data);

//deallocate data, including the terminator character
//calling std::free on the char * returned by mpz_get_str is a bad idea, because it is initialised internally by GMP
(*deallocator)((void *)data, std::char_traits<char>::length(data) + 1);
```

Update 2018: The previous version of the code above was completely wrong. The current version should be correct.

Comment: I used mpz_init but it give me same result. I have  a number which is exact 125 bit. Plz help me

Comment: You're welcome :) Please note that you'll not able to use a standard debugger for the GMP datatypes and you'll have to print them somehow in order to inspect the values. Never trust the debugger because it can be quite misleading. See here for details: http://gmplib.org/manual/Formatted-Output-Strings.html

Comment: how can i print the binary value of any mpz_t variable?